# Rearrange Numpy Matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix as shown below with shape (2, 2, 1).

```
[[[1]
  [3]]

 [[2]
  [4]]]
```

Is there an easy way/function to rearrange the elements such that it becomes:

```
[[[1]
  [2]]

 [[3]
  [4]]]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`swapaxes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) to interchange the two first axes of the array:

```
a.swapaxes(0,1)

array([[[1],
        [2]],

       [[3],
        [4]]])
```